# Target Cache level in PRFM prefetch instructions doesn't seem to have any effect

Tags: arm64, gem5

I want to test prefetch impact for a priori known access patterns. As a first step, I tried to use prefetch instructions using embedded assembler instructions in my executable with the appropriate syntax as found here:
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0802b/PRFM_imm.html

The produced assembly taken by the object dump is the expected for both targeting the L1:

```
0:  340000c1    cbz w1, 18 <_Z8prefetchPhj+0x18>
4:  52800002    mov w2, #0x0                    // #0
8:  f8a26800    prfm    pldl1keep, [x0, x2]
c:  11010042    add w2, w2, #0x40
10: 6b02003f    cmp w1, w2
14: 54ffffa8    b.hi    8 <_Z8prefetchPhj+0x8>  // b.pmore
```

and the L2:

```
0:  340000c1    cbz w1, 18 <_Z8prefetchPhj+0x18>
4:  52800002    mov w2, #0x0                    // #0
8:  f8a26802    prfm    pldl2keep, [x0, x2]
c:  11010042    add w2, w2, #0x40
10: 6b02003f    cmp w1, w2
14: 54ffffa8    b.hi    8 <_Z8prefetchPhj+0x8>  // b.pmore
```

Despite the fact that prefetching works indeed reducing the execution time(Minor CPU model was used in System Emulation Mode), for both cases the output statistics are identical both in terms of execution time and cache behavior. Different cache configurations were tested, all with more than enough capacity to accommodate the prefetched data(of course with no HW prefetching and after making sure that the data are not present in any of the caches). Based on the cache statistics, it seems that both instructions are treated as if they were both targeting the L1 cache.

Is there a different implementation for the different target levels or both instructions are executed by gem5 in the same way? If the latter is the case, is such an expansion included in the future plans?

Comment: Also ping mailing list for this one.

Comment: @CiroSantilli thank you for your reply. Which mailing list do you think I should inform, gem5-dev or gem5-users?

Comment: This one would be gem5-users I believe.